# When to add marzipan?

Tags: baking, cake

I want to bake a cake with the following ingredients:

- 200 g butter
- 200 g sugar
- 200 g grated marzipan
- 4 eggs
- 50 g flour

This is a classic recipe were you cream butter and sugar, add eggs one at the time and fold in the flour. However, I'm in doubt when to add the marzipan for best result.

- Is it best to mix sugar and marzipan first, then start to cream with this mixture?
- Is is it better to cream butter and sugar first, then add marzipan and stir until smooth?

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I would cream together the butter and sugar then add marzipan, eggs and flour in that order